# Cannot call trigger in H2 DB

Tags: java, netbeans, h2

I tried run a simple class to call TRIGGER from Java code, I used H2 DB, can you help me? Here is my simple code (like sample code in H2):

```
public class TriggerTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(TriggerTest.MyTrigger.class.getName());
    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/chap1", "sa", "sa");
    Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
    stat.execute("Drop Table if exists INVOICE");
    stat.execute("Drop Table if exists INVOICE_SUM");
    stat.execute("CREATE TABLE INVOICE(ID INT PRIMARY KEY, AMOUNT DECIMAL)");
    stat.execute("CREATE TABLE INVOICE_SUM(AMOUNT DECIMAL)");
    stat.execute("INSERT INTO INVOICE_SUM VALUES(0.0)");
    stat.execute("CREATE TRIGGER INV_INS AFTER INSERT ON INVOICE FOR EACH ROW CALL \""+TriggerTest.MyTrigger.class.getName()+"\"");
    stat.execute("CREATE TRIGGER INV_UPD AFTER UPDATE ON INVOICE FOR EACH ROW CALL \""+TriggerTest.MyTrigger.class.getName()+"\"");
    stat.execute("CREATE TRIGGER INV_DEL AFTER DELETE ON INVOICE FOR EACH ROW CALL  \""+TriggerTest.MyTrigger.class.getName()+"\"");

    stat.execute("INSERT INTO INVOICE VALUES(1, 10.0)");
    stat.execute("INSERT INTO INVOICE VALUES(2, 19.95)");
    stat.execute("UPDATE INVOICE SET AMOUNT=20.0 WHERE ID=2");
    stat.execute("DELETE FROM INVOICE WHERE ID=1");

    ResultSet rs;
    rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT AMOUNT FROM INVOICE_SUM");
    rs.next();
    System.out.println("The sum is " + rs.getBigDecimal(1));
    conn.close();
}

public static class MyTrigger implements Trigger {

    public void init(Connection conn, String schemaName, String triggerName, String tableName, boolean before, int type) {
        // Initializing trigger
    }

    public void fire(Connection conn,
            Object[] oldRow, Object[] newRow)
            throws SQLException {
        BigDecimal diff = null;
        if (newRow != null) {
            diff = (BigDecimal) newRow[1];
        }
        if (oldRow != null) {
            BigDecimal m = (BigDecimal) oldRow[1];
            diff = diff == null ? m.negate() : diff.subtract(m);
        }
        PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement(
                "UPDATE INVOICE_SUM SET AMOUNT=AMOUNT+?");
        prep.setBigDecimal(1, diff);
        prep.execute();
    }

}
```

And errors :
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Error creating or initializing trigger "INV_INS" object, class "vn.com.khangpn.core.trigger.TriggerTest$MyTrigger", cause: "org.h2.message.DbException: Class ""vn.com.khangpn.core.trigger.TriggerTest$MyTrigger"" not found [90086-169]"; see root cause for details; SQL statement:

Comment: How are you compiling all this? Do you have the proper package statements at the top of your source files? Are the .class files ending up in a folder structure that matches the package name?

Comment: I only run this file from Eclipse..I think when I use TriggerTest.MyTrigger.class.getName(),Call function can read package name, where is wrong?

Answer (score 5):

In H2, [the trigger class must be available in the classpath of the database engine (when using the server mode, it must be in the classpath of the server).](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#triggers)