# How to make my trigger available in classpath (h2 database)

Tags: java, eclipse, triggers, h2

when I invoke query:

```
st.execute("create trigger myTrigger after insert on NEWPOPULATION for each row call "\NewPopulationTrigger\" ");
```

The console write: `Class NewPopulationTrigger not found`

How to should I follow the sentence ["The trigger class must be available in the classpath of the database engine"](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#triggers) - how can I implement it?

My research:
[The example of my issue](https://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/test/org/h2/samples/TriggerSample.java?r=759) /
[adding classpath in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580787/java-based-h2-database-cannot-locate-items-in-classpath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package must be given on the left of the class name.

In the H2 example. The package is `org.h2.samples` and the class is `TriggerSample`

```
CREATE TRIGGER INV_INS AFTER INSERT ON INVOICE
FOR EACH ROW CALL "org.h2.samples.TriggerSample"
```

The clean way in your case is to ask the full name in java:

```
st.execute("create trigger myTrigger after insert on NEWPOPULATION for each row call \""+NewPopulationTrigger.class.getName()+"\"");
```